# Selenium - click a button that hasn't been generated yet

Tags: javascript, c#, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to click a button that does not exist yet on the page. The page source is just a few frames inside a frameset, so the default driver.FindElement() is not working. When I check the DOM, I can see exactly the button I need to click, but don't know how I am supposed to do it.

I have tried using JavaScript executor with no luck

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('menu').getElementsByClassName( 'a' )[0].click()");
```

Comment: If you need to wait for element try Explicit/Implicit wait, if you need to locate element inside frame, use `SwitchTo().Frame()`

Comment: If you stepping through the code in the debugger and wait long enough, so you see the button, is your code able to click the button?
Alternatively, if you put Thread.Sleep(5000) right before the call, does the code work?
What's the error you receive from the driver? Is it a timeout or NoSuchElementException? It looks like the page isn't loaded at the time when you trying to perform a click. You can always add a wait and wait until your element is Displayed and Enabled.

Comment: `SwitchTo().Frame()` was the answer, can't believe I missed that, thanks